# SSJS Activity of automation - Split String using javascript

Tags: javascript, ssjs, automationstudio

I am trying to split string variable in ssjs script but my automation always turns into error
below is my code to split the string:

```
  var str = '<CreatedDate>2018-10-24T04:31:00</CreatedDate>';  
           +'<ModifiedDate>2018-10-24T04:31:00</ModifiedDate>';
           +'<ID>3844854</ID>';
           +'<ObjectID xsi:nil=\"true\" />';
           +'<Status>Active</Status>';
           +'<SubscriberKey>00320000005ccPqAAI</SubscriberKey>';

  var subscriberKey1 = str.split("<SubscriberKey>")[1];
  var subscriberKey = subscriberKey1.split("</SubscriberKey>")[0];
  var modifiedDate1 = str.split("<ModifiedDate>")[1];
  var modifiedDate = modifiedDate1.split("</ModifiedDate>")[0];
  var status1 = str.split("<Status>")[1];
  var status = status1.split("</Status>")[0];
  var createdDate1 = str.split("<CreatedDate>")[1];     
  var createdDate = createdDate1.split("</CreatedDate>")[0];
```

This script gives error and I am unable to find cause because there is no other way of splitting string in SSJS script.
Is it the correct way of splitting string? If NO then please tell me the other way and if yes then why its not working?

Waiting for reply

Answer (score 1):

The data format you're showing is called XML (except you need a root node).

What you're really asking is "How do I parse XML strings in Marketing Cloud's Server Side JavaScript". That question has been answered at the following Salesforce StackExchange link. You'll want to surround your string with a root node first.

[Parse XML in Server Side Javascript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170754/parse-xml-in-server-side-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

`split` is available, and is the right way to split a string. You have syntax errors in your code. If you are concatenating a string over multiple lines, don't end each line with a semicolon.

```
var a = "qwe"
      + "rty";
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, Tried this code and its working