# How to do a dataload from Marketing Cloud to Sales Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I was wondering if there was a way for me to export data from Marketing Cloud and Import it into Sales or Service Cloud.

My use case is I want to export dataviews (_Open, _Clicks, etc.) into Sales or Service Cloud via a dataload tie it to campaign/email information using the SFMC IDs.

I know that with MCC I can create/update records in SFDC using AMPscript/SSJS, but I don't think I could use that for dataviews...I then thought about querying dataviews, adding results to a DE, then referencing that DE as part of an SSJS script and call the SFDC API to create the records...Not sure how realistic that is or if there are any API limitations, just spitballing.

Would appreciate anyone's insight!

Comment: You largely have this data in the IndivdualEmailResults object, no?

Comment: Do you need the data physically in Service Cloud? Email engagement can potentially have huge impact on storage, which will have an impact on your license cost - especially if you want to store each send, open and click event. I would consider using this data as external objects, if this is mainly for the purpose of showing it on e.g a contact page layout.

Comment: probably not a good idea as described in the previous comments. A way to do it can be the Bulk API, which is laid out in the following link. I wouldn't recommend it for this usecase though.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286883/account-activity-or-object-activity-in-journey-builder-has-limits-to-update-like/286998#286998

Comment: @Macca True! I just don't know if it would work for the charts that i want to put together...I'm thinking grouped bar chart of opens, clicks, bounces, etc by each campaign...Think that's a possibility using IER?

Comment: It sure is possible, IER are an object like any other, but the performance in sales cloud is not gonna be great with, say, B2C type volumes of data. Nor is storage cheap in SFSC.