# Mix Automation Studio and Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I'm trying to find a way to fire a Journey only if an Automation ran with success, and then again other steps in the Automation.

More details :
I need to run a SQL query to populate a DE every night with Automation Studio.
Then, I want a Journey to fire on these contacts.
And I need to run some other activities in Automation Studio only if the Journey ran with success.

My idea would be to have a 'journey builder' activity in Automation Studio, so if one step fails, all the other next steps fails too.
It doesn't exists so I'm trying to find a workaround.

Do you have any idea to help me ?

Thanks for your help !

Kind regards,

David

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you mean by 'I need to run some other activities in Auto Studio only if the Journey ran with success'? is this a bulk one time send? If so, why not just use an Email Activity in Automation Studio instead?

Comment: I need to run a SQL query first, then a Journey which will update data in Service Cloud (that's only for admin purposes i'm running this journey), and then -only if the update worked, I'd like to update the AllSubscriber list. It would run every night. Hope it clarifies something !

Comment: What kind of volumes are we talking about? JB shouldn’t really be used for bulk updates - depending on the volume, it might be better to solve this directly in Automation Studio by using the script activity and calling directly the Bulk API in SC

Comment: Around 5/10K per day, so I would say 'not so much'. I'm not familiar with script activities but I may find help in my company for this. Are we talking about running SOAP calls in this script activity ? I understand all would be included in Automation Studio, which may be the easiest to maintain !

Comment: Take a look at answer from Jonas here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286883/account-activity-or-object-activity-in-journey-builder-has-limits-to-update-like

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's pretty clear, I'll give it a try ! How can I mark this question as solved as there is no 'answer' under my question ?