# SFMC ampscript update salesforce object limit

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

We have an email that is meant to generate coupons via ampscript into Sales Cloud.
We use the update salesforce object to generate and assign the coupon (coupon object).
We noticed a discrepancy between how many coopons were assigned and tracked in SFMC compare to how many coupons were generated.

We want to know if there is any records limit when using ampscript/connector to update Sales Cloud and create records as we have over 65k records that failed to generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General advice that I would give is not to use the AMPScript "xySalesforceObject" methods at send time in a bulk sendout (judging from your numbers, that is what you do).

These methods leverage APIs that are not meant / designed for bulk style interaction with Sales Cloud.

That's what SFSC has the Bulk API for (which is also leveraged by Data Loader)- that is where you can get fast mass inserts / upserts.

Journey Builder's SFSC activities have the same situation.
Why do I mention that? You asked for limits, and here I did some load testing a long time ago, and I got to a couple hundred campaignMember updates *per minute* using the standard activity.
The performance is method- and object specific, so don't treat this as exact science. It just helps to understand - yes, there ARE limits, and they must be pretty low. So we can set our expectations and consider whether we are on the right track generally.

I would say:
Creation of records in SFSC(coupons or anything) *at scale*, at send time (or with a near-real-time expectation) is a bad idea.

Either: Create your codes in advance and stream them through the connector.

or: Create them in SFMC at send time, save into a Data Extension using AMPScript or Send Logging, then later, asynchronously push them to your SFSC coupon Object after the sendout using Bulk API.

With that said:
It is possible to leverage the Bulk API as described in the link below, but this is totally different from adding a line of AMPScript into your email, as it works completely differently to a synchronous "add/update data" operation:

Bulk API is more like

- create a job that defines what you want to do (create / insert / update / delete)
- push batches of data into the job that SFSC then processes
- repeat with batches of up to 10k records
- close the job

SFMC implementation pattern described here:

[Account Activity or Object Activity in Journey Builder has limits to update like Data Loader?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286883/account-activity-or-object-activity-in-journey-builder-has-limits-to-update-like/286998#286998)

Hope this helps!