# Passing Encrypted SubscriberKey via UTMs to GA360

Tags: marketing-cloud, google-analytics

We integrated SFMC with GA360 through the out of the box connector. As you're aware, SFMC system generated Contact ID is the key identifier passed by the UTM parameters. Additionally, our intention is to pass the SubscriberKey as well. However, due to compliance we need to encrypt it and then pass to GA360. The encryption and passing of the SubscriberKey is pretty straightforward, we tested and it works. However, we are being told that GA360 might not be able to decrypt the SubscriberKey but only store the encrypted value instead.

Does anyone have experience with this? In addition, would it be possible to do this decryption by Salesforce CRM instead if the data pipeline would be SFMC > GA360 > SFDC CRM.

Comment: how are you encrypting it?

Comment: Why does google need the unencrypted key? GA won't have a "person profile" (and even if: you probably already have one) - GA is used to aggregate. You can aggregate data onto encrypted keys just the same and send that data somewhere else. There, just store encrypted & unencrypted side by side in one system and use that place to actually identify people - if necessary.

Comment: @JonasLamberty indeed, do you know if Salesforce CRM can decrypt an SFMC encrypted value e.g. AES-256?

Comment: Not natively  -There are ways to decrypt something externally that was encrypted with encryptSymmetric() inside SFMC - search this board for "encryptsymmetric" and there are some threads, it depends on the language you try to do it in.

but I wouldnt bother. just store the encrypted key on each record and match google data on the encrypted key. - log the encrypted key in a send log DE and you have "encrypted" and "decrypted" key in a table for everyone that gets an email.

Comment: If you want to push encrypted keys from such a DE to sales cloud at scale, you can use the bulk API - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286883/account-activity-or-object-activity-in-journey-builder-has-limits-to-update-like/286998#286998 - or just match in SFMC and save yourself that as well.

Comment: OK, I'm afraid none of these options would deliver a plausible solution. SFMC ID is passed to GA360 natively, the better solution would be to associate that SFMCID with the account in the CRM and avoid all the other comparisons and matching and passing encrypted values.  I think we will take this one to Salesforce directly. Thanks for the inputs.