# How to use Salesforce Data Extension to update back into Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

we need to update 1 million records on Salesforce CRM from SFMC.
Can you please suggest me any other ways than :

- UpdateSingleSalesforceObject
- Profile Attributes mapping
- Journey Sales Cloud Activity

I read on Salesforce Docs that we can use Salesforce Data Extension to push tracking data into SF CRM, but is it only tracking data ? can we push any data beside tracking data ?

There is a video on youtube that say we can push data from SFMC into Sales Cloud using Salesforce Data Extension, but im not sure how to do that because that video doesn't actually explain about it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does the answer on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286883/account-activity-or-object-activity-in-journey-builder-has-limits-to-update-like help you?

Comment: @SanderdeJong thanks, i haven't tried that Bulk API solution. thank you for informing me