# CloudPageURL function in ssjs activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage

The use case is to send the SMS in marketing cloud via Shortio link shortening service. Now since the Shortio has rate limits, we are first shortening the links, and then upload to data extension and process the send. Since the link is personlised per subscriber, we need to pass some PII parameters in the link. So we need to first create the link apply the cloudpageURL, then shorten the link via shortio.

Thats the reason I am trying to run the SSJS via automation studio, since there the timeout is 30 minutes.

I am trying to find the cloudpageurl function for SSJS activity in autumation studio, I want to use the automation studio activity as need to convert 66k records with the function, and cloud page time out in 2 minutes, which is not enough to process the 66k records.

In cloudpage below function works

```
var cloudPageUrl = Platform.Function.TreatAsContent('%%=CloudPagesURL("IDofthecloudpage", "params", "' + longUrl + '")=%%');
```

However in Automation studio SSJS activity since ampscript cants be used, I used below

```
var cloudPageUrl = "https://mydomain.pub.sfmc-content.com/cloudpages/" + cloudPageId + ".aspx?qs=" + Platform.Function.UrlEncode("params=" + longUrl);
```

This did not generated the query string.

Thanks

Comment: You can use ampscript in a script activity, see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146111/using-ampscript-in-a-script-activity

Comment: Thank you. This solution wont work on my end due to timeout issues. I need to process around 66k records.

Comment: As was said, you can execute AMPScript from ssjs, but generally you are on the wrong track if you intend to use script for that amount of records. a) Try to do most of the heavy lifting with SQL, and for the rest, b)  build loops using alternating automations that are batching small enough to individually not time out. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/415648/ssjs-script-is-timing-out-at-30-minutes-how-to-i-build-series-of-scripts-using . This is not an easy addon to an existing solution but your problem is built into the methods you are using.

Comment: Script Activities and Cloud pages time out... but, you can use this method I developed: [link](https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-prevent-your-scripts-from-timing-out-on-cloud-pages/) The only catch is that you'll have to keep your browser opened for a long period of time.

Comment: Thank you, Ivan for this link, I will have a look.