external api call when people unsubscribe in Market Cloud
What is the correct way to handle this situation: if a user unsubscribes in Market Cloud, will an API call trigger and send the user's email to another system?

I should use automation studio or Journey Builder to create
this?
From online I found some resource about the SSJS

below:
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1"); // Load the core library

// Define Magento API endpoint and bearer token
var magentoEndpoint = "https://www.abc.com/rest/V1/newsletter/subscription/"; // Update with the appropriate endpoint
var bearerToken = "ABCDEDSDwn0122143343242";

// Define the email to unsubscribe
var emailToUnsubscribe = "test_26@gmail.com"; // Change this to the email you want to unsubscribe

// Make the API call to Magento
try {
  var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
  var headerValues = ["Bearer " + bearerToken];
  
  var response = HTTP.Delete(magentoEndpoint + encodeURIComponent(emailToUnsubscribe), headerNames, headerValues);
  
  // Handle response
  if (response.StatusCode == 200) {
    // Unsubscribe successful
    Write("Unsubscribe successful");
  } else {
    // Unsubscribe failed
    Write("Unsubscribe failed. StatusCode: " + response.StatusCode);
    Write("Response: " + response.Response);
  }
} catch (ex) {
  Write("Error: " + ex.message);
}
</script>



The base premise is flawed.
There are multiple ways to unsubscribe oneself;
Writing an API call that you route unsubscribers against is one way. (think email footer) - but that solution will be incomplete. So any custom unsub API sending data somewhere cannot send complete data. Which to me sounds like a reason not to invest time and effort.
The business case is questionable:
What does an external system do with this real-time information?

Send emails, too?
a) migration off a legacy system - I read marketo? then think about a synch once daily, saves yourself a lot of trouble, - check this with legal - is probably compliant as well, and your solution will die with the legacy system anyway.
b) keeping parallel sendout systems long-term? that's a bad idea on multiple levels. This topic being one.

Display it & manipulate it on individual level? then think about a retrieval api and a "manipulation" API, not cloning all data, and especially not in real time.


The solution can be achieved with asynchronous methods
You will have to deal with incoming "list unsubscriptions" circumventing your API directly into the backend, e.g. from complaints, list-unsubscribe header, replies; essentially, anything in (all the local variants of) the _Unsubscribe Data view, which you retrieve from with SQL.
That's the only thing all the unsub types have in common (including, hopefully, your custom API): logUnsubEvent is the engine behind them, which write to the _Unsubscribe.
Problem: you cannot react on "row created" type symptoms (an unsub event was logged) inside Marketing Cloud in real time, only with time-based retrievals like SQL. Coming back to my earlier suggestion - do a daily synch, but with the benefit of having full instead of partial data.
Thought experiment, not a suggestion:
With VERY limited scope and scaling, you could react on a ripple effect of logUnsubEvent, given Marketing Cloud Connect were installed and you'd be ok with doing this on ANY unsubscription of any kind at any level in your org (because you could retrieve more context somehow).
You could react on the field change of "hasOptedOutOfEmail" in Sales Cloud, which itself seems to react directly to the backend, in real-time using e.g. flows. Which enter a third system into the mix, making things even messier.

Thank you, Joans, for your comments. Perhaps I haven't explained well enough. We are using SF MC to manage all subscriptions. However, when a customer unsubscribes on the SF MC page, my other platform doesn't receive notification that the person has unsubscribed in SF MC. Therefore, I was thinking that if I can use Automation Studio to query the last 24 unsubscribes from the Data Extension table, it will trigger an API call to the third-party platform to unsubscribe them there as well. But anyway I am appreciate your response

That absolutely works using Script activities; The problem will be bulkifying / batching your API calls, in case the external system has a bulk style API; see here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286883/account-activity-or-object-activity-in-journey-builder-has-limits-to-update-like/286998#286998; if not, it will get a LOT of API calls, which might be your next problem. If you can it would be way easier to drop to sftp / S3.
