# SSJS API call to retrieve XML and parse it

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio, marketingcloudapi

We need to perform following using SSJS in Automation studio:

1. We need to do a API call to get a XML response.
2. We need to parse that that XML response and store values in data extension.

I am are trying to use "Script.Util.HttpGet" method to retrieve data from XML.

Whenever I use HTTPget method with HTML webpage, I get the response and I can write it using "Platform.Response.Write".

For example: Code to retrieve HTML document
"

```
<script runat="server">
   var req = new Script.Util.HttpGet("http://www.example.com/");
   var resp = req.send();
   Platform.Response.Write("Content:"+resp.content);
</script>
```

"

But Whenever I try to retrieve a data from any XML document by passing URL for XML document, it is not writing anything. How can I write to see what data it retrieved from xml?

code to retrieve XML:
"

```
<script runat="server">
   var req = new Script.Util.HttpGet("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml");
   var resp = req.send();
   Platform.Response.Write("Content:"+resp.content );
</script>
```

"

I am not sure how to get response from XML and parse it.
I need to verify xml response and store the node values in data extension.
Can someone already worked on such requirement to do a api call to get XML response and parse and store it in DE ?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Please check the following code for my example :
Note, I am retrieving xml from "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml" for this example.

```
<h1> Attendees Data </h1>
  <br>
  <script runat="server">
    var url = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml";
    var req = new Script.Util.HttpGet(url);
    var resp = req.send();
    var respString = Platform.Function.Stringify(resp.content);
    Platform.Response.Write("Response:<br/ >"+ respString +"<br />");
    Platform.Response.Write("Response String Content:<br/ >"+respString.content +"<br />");
    function trim(x) {
      return x.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
    };
    function dataFromAttr(data, attr, notNull){
      if (data){
        var reg = new RegExp("<"+attr+">", "g");
        var result = data.match(reg);
        if(result.length == 0){
          var str = '';
          return trim(str);
        }
        if(result.length == 1){
          var str = data.split("<"+attr+">")[1];
          str = str.split("</"+attr+">")[0];
          return trim(str);
        }
        if(result.length > 1){
          var str = data.split("</"+attr+"> <"+attr+">");
          return str;
        }
        var nullElementValue = new RegExp("<"+attr+" />");
        if(data.match(nullElementValue).length) return "";
        if(notNull) return "";
      }
      else{
        return null;
      }
    };
    
    var pname = dataFromAttr(respString, "name");
    var pprice = dataFromAttr(respString, "price");

    Platform.Response.Write("pname:<br/ >"+ pname +"<br />");
    
  </script>
```

When I stringify the response and print
i.e.  `Platform.Response.Write("Response:<br/ >"+ respString+"<br />");`
it will return the values of nodes but not nodes and properties. Check the response below after stringify:

**""\r\n\r\n \r\n Belgian Waffles\r\n $5.95\r\n Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup\r\n 650\r\n \r\n \r\n Strawberry Belgian Waffles\r\n $7.95\r\n Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream\r\n 900\r\n \r\n \r\n Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles\r\n $8.95\r\n Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream\r\n 900\r\n \r\n \r\n French Toast\r\n $4.50\r\n Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread\r\n 600\r\n \r\n \r\n Homestyle Breakfast\r\n $6.95\r\n Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns\r\n 950\r\n \r\n\r\n"**

Thank You,
Vikram

Comment: This could help https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170754/parse-xml-in-server-side-javascript

Comment: Hi Jonas, Thanks for the reply. I went through the example. But not sure what exactly passed in "Client" variable in the example provided. I tried to pass response and also the stringified response but no success.

Comment: Hi All, Is any body worked on api call to get xml response and parse it?

Answer (score 1):

To write the response, you need to stringify it first, so try:

```
Platform.Response.Write("Content:"+Stringify(resp));
```

For parsing XML, there are no specific SSJS functions, but you can do it using regex.

See this thread for details: [Parse XML in Server Side Javascript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170754/parse-xml-in-server-side-javascript)

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj, Thanks for the response. Stringify will print the values of nodes. But I want to print xml with all nodes. I went through the example provided i.e. "Parse XML in Server Side Javascript". But I am not able to retrieve the nodes. In the example, they passed "Client" variable to a method i.e. "dataFromAttr(client, "home_phone")" . So what would be the "Client" variable. Is it XML response or XML response after stringify. I tried passing both, but no success? Can anyone let me know what I am missing here?

Comment: Client is the name of the XML element that they wanted to display values from. Were you able to write the XML response? Can you paste the structure here?

Comment: Hi  zuzannamj , I updated the question with the code I have.

Comment: OK, in Eliot's example `Client` was the element that he wanted to retrieve information from. In your case, the element is called `food` and it has properties such as `name`, `price`, etc so I assume you would want to retrieve those

Comment: Yes. Correct! but no success... When I stringify and print the content I can see all the values present in the nodes but not the actual nodes (XML nodes with properties)

Comment: OK, can you include that in your original question? just copy and paste the stringified response that you see

Comment: Updated the question with the stringify response output