# Send Marketing Cloud email out when RSS Feed updates

Tags: marketing-cloud, trigger, api, rss

I have a working email that populates with the RSS feed code, but I am now wondering how can I automate this email to send out to its subscribers whenever there is a new post/article on the RSS xml. I am not sure what the best way to approach this (API, automation, query, Journey, interaction). Any insight / article will be helpful in pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to run an automation on regular basis, which parses the XML from the RSS file, and compares the time stamp of the most recent item with the one which was stored upon your last email send. If these differ, then the automation could trigger an automated email. Here are some resources to get you started:

1. [Parse XML in Server Side Javascript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170754/parse-xml-in-server-side-javascript)
2. [Verification activity](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_as_verification_activity.htm&language=en_US)
3. [Send Email Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_as_send_email_activity.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the articles and direction!